# Using min/max operations in groupByKey on a spark dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve `min` and `max` inside `agg` of a `groupByKey` operation. The code looks like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang.typed.{
  count => typedCount, 
  sum => typedSum }

inputFlowRecords.groupByKey(inputFlowRecrd => inputFlowRecrd.FlowInformation)
  .agg(typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.minFlowTime).name("minFlowTime"),
      typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.maxFlowTime).name("maxFlowTime"),
      typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.flowStartedCount).name("flowStartedCount"),
      typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.flowEndedCount).name("flowEndedCount"),
      typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.packetsCountFromSource).name("packetsCountFromSource"),
      typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.bytesCountFromSource).name("bytesCountFromSource"),
      typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.packetsCountFromDestination).name("packetsCountFromDestination"),
      typedSum[InputFlowRecordV1](_.FlowStatistics.bytesCountFromDestination).name("bytesCountFromDestination"))
```

I am facing 2 problems here:

1. Instead of sum I want to take min/max on few columns. When I try to use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.min/max` operations, the error says TypedColumns should be used. How can this be solved?
2. The `agg` function lets us specify only 4 columns max. inside it while I have 8 columns to aggregate. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems that:

- min/max are not yet supported (see "todos" in [typed.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/scalalang/typed.scala))
- agg function indeed only supports up to 4 columns (see in [KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala))

In your case a reasonable thing to do might be to define your own specialized aggregator that would aggregate `InputFlowStatistics` objects, so you only have single argument to `agg`.

Typed aggregators are defined here: [typedaggregators.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/aggregate/typedaggregators.scala) and Spark documentation provides some information on creating custom ones (->[link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#type-safe-user-defined-aggregate-functions)).

Comment: Any suggestions to handle the min/max operations?